# Can you still earn the diablo 3 kerrigan wings if you buy Starcraft 2 now?

Tags: diablo-iii, starcraft-2

Is this still possible or was it only for pre-ordering?

Comment: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/buy-now/digital-deluxe the quantity never runs out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wings are not a pre-order bonus, but a Deluxe/Collectors Edition bonus.

So if you get the deluxe digital or Collectors Edition  you will get the wings.

Answer (score 5):

The Diablo 3 Kerrigan wings are a bonus part of the [Collectors Edition](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/buy-now/collectors-edition) or the [Digital Deluxe](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/buy-now/digital-deluxe) version.  You can purchase either of these now and once you bind the Starcraft II: Heart of the Swarm key to your account you will be able to get the Kerrigan wings on Diablo III.

Answer (score 3):

They are part of the [Deluxe Edition](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/buy-now/digital-deluxe) so you can get them anytime you want, upon buying this version. Also, if you buy the Standard Edition, you can still upgrade in the future to Deluxe Edition and still get all your rewards